# why my attr_cls and attr_ins behave differently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes

why my attr_cls and attr_ins behave differently?

```
class D:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def __get__(self, ins, owner):
        return self._name


class A:

    attr_cls = D('John')    # <----

    def __init__(self):   
        self.attr_ins = D('John')   # <----


a = A()

print(a.attr_cls)    # John
print(a.attr_ins)    # <__main__.D object at 0x0000000003836DD8>
```

is there any difference between those two when I'm dealing with A class instance? i mean `a.attr_cls` and `a.attr_ins` seem the same to me. thank you for your answers.

Comment: Because `D` is a descriptor, a descriptor's lookup on instance and class works differently. `a.attr_cls ` is equivalent to `type(a).__dict__['attr_cls '].__get__(a, type(a))`. You should read the docs: [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html). Secondly descriptors only work at class level not instance level.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary "You should read the docs: " I'm just trying to understand those docs `: (` . now its a little more clear

Comment: Cite the parts of docs that you couldn't understand in the question. The readers of the question don't know what does the OP knows what they doesn't. :-)